# How to make a Bar Chart in Grafana

Tags: json, grafana

I'm not being able to print the chart I want

·Imported data from Infinity plugin
·GET my API endpoint successfully
·Data is showing as a table correctly (City from which user is in JSON)

Data I want to show: Each bar shows a single City (X Axis), when Y Axis shows user quantity

The issue is that I can input the X axis, but there is no Y axis
I can't figure this out, what am I missing?

I've tried different charts, but didn't get a single one working properly :(
I think there is some time stuff or data transformation that I need, but couldn't find the answer on internet

**Please provide some link or suggestion to read since I'm new to Grafana**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DONE,

I was passing data as STRING not as NUMBER so grafana didn't know what to do with those =)